# How to restore Ubuntu 16.0.4 Window Manager

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm

I removed mono, monodev and all dependencies from my machine (using **apt-get remove ---purge** etc), but I was a bit overzealous and also removed **ubuntu-mono** that seems to have a whole ton of dependencies, and I watched in horror as seemingly unrelated applications like firefox(??!) were uninstalled from the machine.

To add insult to injury, my Window Manager (Unity - I guess), was uninstalled too, and I was dumped unceremoniously, back to the command prompt.

Upon restarting the machine, I realised I couldn't even login.

Half a day later, I reinstall **xorg, lighdm and ubuntu-desktop**, I was then able to log into the machine - but was greeted with a ghastly window manager (terminal is green characters on white background - seriously??!!). And I no longer have the ability to change the window manager during login - the options are no longer presented during login.

I want top revert back to the Window Manager and settings that comes with Ubuntu 16.0.4 - it would seem no one has experienced this particular set of events - because I can't seem to find any documentation on how to resolve it.

This is the content of `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=ubuntu
```

Here is some other miscellaneous useful information:

```
me@YOURBOX:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
Unity
me@YOURBOX:~$ echo $GDMSESSION
ubuntu

me@YOURBOX:~$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 204 Nov 12  2015 ubuntu.desktop
```

How do I revert back to the Window Manager and defaults provided out of the box with Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS?